# Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined -- Script loading order?

Tags: angularjs

For the `concat` block of my Gruntfile.js:

```
    concat: {
        options: {
            stripBanners: false,
            banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
            '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
        },
        production: {
          files: {
            './public/js/build/services.js': ['./public/js/services/*.js'],
            './public/js/build/factories.js': ['./public/js/factories/*.js'],
            './public/js/build/controllers.js': ['./public/js/controllers/*.js'],
            './public/js/build/directives.js': ['./public/js/directives/*.js'],
            './public/js/build/filters.js': ['./public/js/filters/*.js'],
            './public/js/build/plugins.js': ['./public/js/plugins/*.js'],
            './public/js/build/modern-angular.js': [
                './public/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                './public/bower_components/angular-stable/angular.js',
                './public/bower_components/angular-sanitize-stable/angular-sanitize.js'
            ],
            './public/js/build/old-angular.js': [
                './public/bower_components/jquery-1.11/index.js',
                './public/bower_components/angular-unstable/angular.js',
                './public/bower_components/angular-sanitize-unstable/angular-sanitize.js',
                './public/bower_components/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js'
            ],
            './public/js/build/app.js': [
                './public/js/app.js',
                './public/js/build/services.js',
                './public/js/build/factories.js',
                './public/js/build/controllers.js',
                './public/js/build/directives.js',
                './public/js/build/filters.js',
                './public/js/build/plugins.js'
            ]
          }
        }
    },
```

As you may be able to tell with my Gruntfile.js, I'm required to support old, outdated browsers, therefor I have to load two different versions of Angular depending on the browser.

Here's my index.ejs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="ng-app:idocs" id="ng-app" ng-app="idocs" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
    <head>

        <!-- Omitting to prevent bloating -->

        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <script> var olderIE = true; </script>
        <![endif]-->

        <script>
            if (typeof olderIE === 'undefined') {
                // User is using a modern browser, they're awesome.
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.setAttribute('src', '/js/build/modern-angular.js');
                document.head.appendChild(script);
            }
        </script>

        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <script src="/js/build/old-angular.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>
    <body data-ng-cloak onload="handleTaggerEvent()">

        <!-- Again, omitting -->

        <% if(nodeEnv == 'production') { %>
            <script src="/js/build/app.js"></script>
        <% } else { %>
            <script src="/js/build/controllers.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/build/directives.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/build/factories.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/build/filters.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/build/plugins.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/build/templates.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
        <% } %>

        <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = {
                // Omitting for brevity
            };

            // Socket.io stuff
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in the browser I get littered with the following error.  Angular appears to load, but after the rest of the angular code:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting the error because you are loading the controllers, directives, factories, filters and such before you actually load angular files. You need to load the angular files. Should look something like this:

```
'./public/js/build/modern-angular.js': [
                    './public/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                    './public/bower_components/angular-stable/angular.js',
                    './public/bower_components/angular-sanitize-stable/angular-sanitize.js'
                ],     
'./public/js/build/services.js': ['./public/js/services/*.js'],
                './public/js/build/factories.js': ['./public/js/factories/*.js'],
                './public/js/build/controllers.js': ['./public/js/controllers/*.js'],
                './public/js/build/directives.js': ['./public/js/directives/*.js'],
                './public/js/build/filters.js': ['./public/js/filters/*.js'],
                './public/js/build/plugins.js': ['./public/js/plugins/*.js'],
```

This would allow for the angular-stable/angular.js files to load before the other files.Your previous version loads because you load all the files after the angular files a second time. Try removing one of the copies of:

```
        './public/js/build/app.js': [
            './public/js/app.js',
            './public/js/build/services.js',
            './public/js/build/factories.js',
            './public/js/build/controllers.js',
            './public/js/build/directives.js',
            './public/js/build/filters.js',
            './public/js/build/plugins.js'
        ]
```

That should work.

Comment: I'm confused how switching the order of what files are generated via a concat while running grunt would affect the load order of scripts in a browser.  Also, what are you referring to when you say "one of the copies of"?  `./public/js/build/app.js` is the only occurrence of that file in the concat.

Comment: From the code, it appears that the './public/js/build/*' files are instituted before and after the angular docs. I believe the ones before the angular docs are creating the error because the browser order needs something like: jquery, angular, angular-sanitize,  app.js, factories - filters.

Answer (score 0):

Add this two line before script tab

```
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
```